# Inconsistent behavior between class and typedef

Tags: flutter, class, dart, typedef

the code below gives an error, assuming that it's intended and not a bug

```dart
class Bar {}

class Baz extends Bar {}

typedef Foo<T extends Bar> = void Function(T);

void printBaz(Baz baz) => print(baz);

final list = <Foo>[];

class Fiz<T extends Bar> {
  final T data;
  Fiz(this.data);
}

void main(){
  final fiz = Fiz(Baz()); /// of course no problem!
  
  list.add(printBaz); 
  /// The argument type 'void Function(Baz)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(Bar)
}
```

can anyone explain me the reason of this behavior
that seems to be inconsistent across `typedef` and `class`

also a way to circumvent the error will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behavior. It has to do with the typing on your `list`. Since you do not specify the generic when you declare the list, only specifying any `Foo`, the inferred type is a `List<Foo<Bar>>`, because `Bar` is the most generic type you allow `Foo`s to take.

`printBaz` does not know how to handle a `Bar` parameter, therefore it cannot be added to your list and you get a linter error.

This can be solved by providing the generic argument on `Foo` when you declare and initialize your list:

```dart
final list = <Foo<Baz>>[];
```